# Use data result from login test to other test

Tags: testng, spring-test

I need to access the token provided by successful login in SecurityITest.login in another class user for Bearer value in the header. Where is the best place to store the token generated by login so that it can be access by other test (in or outside the class)

**BaseITest**

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class BaseITest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

}
```

**SecurityIITest**

```
public class SecurityIITest extends BaseITest {

    @Value("${bootstrap.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${bootstrap.password}")
    private String password;

    @BeforeSuite(groups = {"security"})
    public void login() throws Exception {
        String jsonResult = mvc.perform(post(ApiUrls.LOGIN)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .param("username", username)
                .param("password", password))

                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath(JsonField.TOKEN).exists())
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JsonNode result = mapper.readTree(jsonResult);

        // this token to reuse in other methods from other class
        // token = result.get("token").asText();

    }

}
```

**AccountControllerITest**

```
public class AccountControllerITest extends BaseITest {
   @Test(dependsOnGroups = {"security"})
    public void postAccount() throws Exception {
        // need to access token here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tests are within the same `<test>` tag then you can share data across multiple `@Test` methods that are part of it, by :

**To set data**

```
Object object = new Object();
Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().setAttribute("foo", object);
```

**To get data**

```
Object obj = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getAttribute("foo");
```

from within a `@Test` method.

If the tests are within different `<test>` tag, but within the same `<suite>` then you can share data by invoking

**To set data**

```
Object object = new Object();
Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getSuite().setAttribute("foo", object);
```

**To get data**

```
Object obj = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getSuite().getAttribute("foo");
```

from within a `@Test` method.